# Recommended Media Size for Twenty Fourteen

Tags: themes, post-thumbnails, media-settings

is there a recommended media size for Thumbnail size in twenty fourteen? am trying to sort out my website so that it doesn't serve any resized media on the home page, most of the resized media are coming from the featured image on the home page. When i test the page speed i get "The following images are resized in HTML or CSS"

Any help on the thumbnail media size wold be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twenty Fourteen uses 2 custom media sizes:

- 672x372px for post thumbnail image size
- and 1038x576px for 'twentyfourteen-full-width' custom image size

So for images uploaded *after* the theme is activated, these 2 size are created automatically, but for images uploaded *before* twentyfourteen is activated, an available size is used and image is resized via html/css properties.

What I suggest is for new images upload files having width >= 1038 px and height >= 576 px and let theme resize them.

For images already uploaded a plugin like [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) can be very usefull (but images must be larger than custom size required by theme or the thumbnail will not be generated).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I activated the Photon in jetpack and it sorted the images out, i tried the thumbnail regeneration but it doesn't work for some reason.